# Android Camera Effects Not Working

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I'm trying to build an image editing app for android and I've just started and already I'm having trouble. Well I can take a picture and save to the sd card. But i try to do some effects the app is running but the effects don't show up in the preview. Heres the complete code that i use:

```
package com.example.camerademo;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.hardware.Camera;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import android.view.SurfaceView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity implements 

SurfaceHolder.Callback {

SurfaceView cameraView;

SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

Camera camera;





@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

cameraView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.CameraView);

surfaceHolder = cameraView.getHolder();

surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);


}





@Override

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,int height) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



    camera.startPreview();


}

@Override

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    camera = Camera.open();

    try {

    camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);

    camera.setParameters(parameters);



    }

    catch (IOException exception)

    {

    camera.release();

    }

    }



@Override

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    camera.stopPreview();

    camera.release();

}}
```

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with my code for effects. Is the a any other way 
of doing it?

Heres the code i used to get the supported effects and loop through it.

```
List<String> colorEffects = parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
Iterator<String> cei = colorEffects.iterator();
while (cei.hasNext())
{
String currentEffect = cei.next();
if (currentEffect.equals(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE))
{
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
break;
}
}
```

This gives me a null pointer exception.. So i tried to see if colorEffects holds any data or effects. I used an if loop like this

```
if(colorEffects == null){
editText.setText("Null");
}
```

And it was null. Why? Is there some problem with the downloaded sdk. Should I download android 2.3 SDK. Currently i have 2.2 SDK downloaded. Btw even if just type

```
parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
```

without using getSupportedColorEffects() method it runs without errors but the effect doesn't show up in preview.

Log Cat Information:

```
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at com.example.camerademo.MainActivity.surfaceCreated(MainActivity.java:56)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:532)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.SurfaceView.dispatchDraw(SurfaceView.java:339)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-01 00:08:17.588: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This error occurs when i enter this line of code:

```
List<String> colorEffects = parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
    Iterator<String> cei = colorEffects.iterator();
    while (cei.hasNext())
    {
    String currentEffect = cei.next();
    if (currentEffect.equals(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE))
    {
    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
    break;
    }
    }
```

Comment: How about the stack trace of your error?

Comment: Is my code right? @WarrenFaith do u know any other way of doing it?

Comment: Without a stack trace I am not willing to look at your code. Sorry but a stack trace belongs to a good error description.

Comment: In the previous code i got a null pointer exception. There i used the getsupportedcoloreffects() method and used an iterator to go through the list. But as i said i got a null pointer exception. So that means the getsupportedcoloreffects() doesn't get anything...
I updated my question. Check what i did there...

Comment: What is so difficult in putting a stack trace in the question and point to the line of code where it occurs?

Comment: @WarrenFaith Sorry. The computer on which i had this app had some problem. I have put the log cat info in the question.

Comment: @WarrenFaith What should I do? I need to get this to work...

Comment: What exactly is line 56?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try put these lines:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);

camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

into `surfaceChanged` method?

This is the sample code I copied from [Android Developers Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera):

```
 public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
          // preview surface does not exist
          return;
        }

        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e){
          // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }

        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here

        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

According to this reference, it is recommend to put any changes in `surfaceChanged` method just like the what the comments are saying.

I've similar app that will change the size of preview and I followed the guide. So could you try this method?

Comment: @maestrosan11 please let me know the result :)