# getSupportedColorEfffects() method returning null data

Tags: android, camera, android-camera

I'm doing an android camera app. And when I try to set the color effects it does not work.
Btw I've posted another question regarding this here:
[Android Camera Effects Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902101/android-camera-effects-not-working/13913098#comment19205383_13913098)
I was using this code to go through the effects and see which was supported by my device.

```
List<String> colorEffects = parameters.getSupportedColorEffects();
Iterator<String> cei = colorEffects.iterator();
while (cei.hasNext())
{
    String currentEffect = cei.next();
    if (currentEffect.equals(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE))
    {
        parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NEGATIVE);
        break;
    }
}
```

But this gives me a null pointer exception. So I checked if `getSupportedColorEffects()` returns anything.

```
if (colorEffects == null){
    editText.setText("Null");
}
```

And it did return `null`. Why? Is something wrong with the downloaded Android SDK? Should I download a new version. I've downloaded Android 2.2, should I download Android 2.3 and see what happens?

Comment: Where/how do you declare & initialise parameters instance?

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13902101/android-camera-effects-not-working/13913098#comment19205383_13913098

Answer (score 0):

This function is not always supported by a camera module. [See the definition of the function according to Android.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedColorEffects%28%29)

Basically, it just depends on the specific phone's camera hardware and setup, and it looks like the phone you are using does not support color effects.

Comment: Ok. But even when i run the code with that getSupportedColorEffects() method in eclipse it force closes. Atleast it should run in eclipse. I get a null pointer exception a i said earlier. Thats why i was thinking there may be some problem with the downloaded Android OS version....

Comment: Btw if  i just give the parameters for the effect directly, the code runs on my phone but the effect doesn't show up in the preview...